# Implementing Checkmarx suggested clickjacking fix introduces high severity Client DOM XSS vulnerability

Tags: javascript, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding, clickjacking

My organization has scanned our code using Checkmarx and the low severity issue **Potential Clickjacking on Legacy Browsers** was detected due to a JavaScript function firing on an HTML image click event.

We have implemented the following suggested fixes:

- Define and implement a Content Security Policy (CSP) on the server
  side, including a frame-ancestors directive (frame-ancestors 'self')
- "X-Frame-Options" header set to "SAMEORIGIN"
- Legacy browser support is needed so added a frame-busting script similar to the following example in the Checkmarx documentation:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style> html {display : none; } </style>
        <script>
            if ( self === top ) {
                document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                top.location = self.location;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="clicked();">Click here if you love ducks</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now Checkmarx flags the file for the high severity issue **Client DOM XSS** due to the line:

```
top.location = self.location;
```

that was recommended to be added for legacy click jack protection.

So if we implement the Checkmarx suggested fix on a low severity issue (Potential Clickjacking on Legacy Browsers), we introduce a high severity issue (Client DOM XSS).

What's the proper course of action here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the risk of a [DOM-based cross-site scripting](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/DOM_Based_XSS) vulnerability in your web application, URL encode the self.location

```
top.location = encodeURI(self.location);
```